# RTorrent help disabling tracker for target

Tags: bittorrent, torrent

I have a torrent of a Linux image saved in my home directory, I added it to rtorrent via:

`rtorrent /home/echo/linux.iso.torrent`

However, I keep getting the error:

`tracker couldn't connect to server`

Since the torrent is locally saved, I figured I didn't need any trackers, so I found the command to disable it:

`t.disable = ‹target› ≫ 0`

from here:

https://rtorrent-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd-ref.html#term-load-start

I'm new, I'm a little confused on what my "target" is. Also, I've never used any rtorrent commands yet, I assume once I run the program, I press enter and type the command at the load.normal> prompt?

If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: A torrent client needs to connect to a tracker, other peers, or the DHT network to get other peers to download from.  Why do you want to disable trackers?

Comment: I mentioned above, the download wouldn't start because I kept getting an error that the tracker couldn't connect to a server.  I only wanted to remedy this by disabling the tracker because I thought it wasn't needed.  Thanks to you, I now know that they're necessary, so how would you go about fixing this error?